# How to Loop youtube videos

Tags: loops, youtube, repeat

I am trying to learn guitar these days. This requires me to play some videos on repeat for some number of times. What are the best sites for looping youtube videos?

Comment: This isn't really a coding question, even though I answered, myself - you should post it on Super User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of options available online to loop youtube videos. I am listing a few of them here (the ones which I use frequently)-

1. http://listenonrepeat.com -> visually looks good
2. http://youtuberepeat.com -> small footprint on your browser
3. http://youtubepipe.com -> dimmed background. video is focused.
4. http://yourepeat.com -> visually looks good. Provides extension for Chrome.

These sites run on almost all desktop browsers. Can't say the same for mobile browsers.

EDIT

Appending &loop=1 to youtube URL doesn't work nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click your youtube video, you will see this menu:

[image: watching Don't Stop Me Now - loop on youtube]

Just click loop (to undo press loop again).

Answer (score -1):

For practicing by ear and learning songs by looping YouTube videos, use LoopTube https://www.looptube.xyz

You can load any YouTube video, set start and end points to loop any part of the tune. Then slow it down to a suitable speed and practice by repeating the loop.

When you've learned that part, you can shift the loop forward by the same time window so that it moves on to the next phrase to learn.